# link to start my workflow on my list not showing

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server

i already create my workflow with sharepoint desinger and i publish it to my libreary 
the column(send mail) was added but the link to start myworkflow does not exist [image]

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot doesn't help a ton as I wouldn't expect to see a link to start the workflow in that view w/o custom code being used. When you click on the ellipses next to an item (...) and go to workflows, do you see the workflow you created? If not, you may not have associated the workflow properly.

You can also check the workflow associations (List tab > Workflow Settings) and see if any workflows are associated as well as to click the Add a Workflow link if none show. If your workflow is not available to be associated, then you may have an issue with which list you chose to associate this with or with your changes being saved correctly.

Comment: i suppose to found a link to start my workflow under "send email"